# Search a form using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am currently trying to find an address based on zip code using Ajax.

When I execute it, it returns an unexpected display. Instead of having a list of addresses with a search form, the list is repeated several times until it returns an error.

Can anyone provide any clarification?

The file :index.html.twig

```html
<div class="loading"></div>

    {% include 'LesproduwebBundle:Adresse:index.html.twig' with {'entities':entities }  %}

 
<script>
$(".loading").hide();
$("#form_recherche").submit(function(){
    $(".loading").show();
    var codePostal = $("#codepostal").val();
    var DATA = 'codePostal=' + codePostal;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('adresse_recherhe')}}",
        data: DATA,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           $('#resultats_recherche').html(data);
           $(".loading").hide();
        }
    });   
    return false;
});
</script>
```

The Controller

```html
public function rechercherAction()
{              
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
 
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $codePostal = '';
        $codePostal = $request->request->get('codePostal');
 
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
 
         if($codePostal != '')
        {
               $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
 
               $qb->select('a')
                  ->from('LesproduwebBundle:Adresse', 'a')
                  ->where("a.codePostal LIKE :codePostal")
                 
                  ->setParameter('codePostal', '%'.$codePostal.'%');
 
               $query = $qb->getQuery();              
               $entities  = $query->getResult();
        }
        else {
            $adresse = $em->getRepository('LesproduwebBundle:Adresse')->findAll();
        }
 
        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('LesproduwebBundle:Adresse:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities ' => $entities 
            ));
    }
    else {
        return $this->indexAction();
    }
```

Comment: Putting the code directly is a lot better than posting screenshots of the code. it's better to provide the error message that you get. If you do so there is 90% that you will get an answer. Otherwise no one will answer you trust me

Comment: I can't put it in the comment

Comment: You can edit your answer and put the code there ( there is and  edit link )

Comment: good Dhouha :) you have edited your question, I can't see an error in your code, could you add the error that you get maybe it could help to find the problem

Comment: there is no screenshot.

Comment: the form is repeated several times
this is the error